# Gassuian mixture model visualization

Tags: data-visualization, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a GMM-distributed vector with $K$ components.
In the setting where we consider diagonal covariances, we have $P1=K\cdot (n+n)+K$, i.e. linear in $n$ and $K$, and $P_2=K(n^2/2+n)+K$, quadratic in $n$ and linear in $K$, in case of full covariance matrices.

Even in a moderate number of parameters, $n=10$, $K=20$, we have hundreds of parameters.

I see that it is common to observe the mixture proportions ($\pi_k$), but it there a known way to visualize the entire distribution, that's easier than inspecting a parameter space that's in the hundreds or more?

Comment: Can you post a small example dataset to give people something to work with?